# How to generate sequence of steps like Flowchart using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a requirement where I need to generate a sequence of steps for one of the features in my application.

Steps will be like, Flow starts with step1 & next step is step2 & any step can be even divided into multiple steps.

Can any one of you please advice me on how to implement this in my AngularJS application.

Expected JSON can be found below.

{
  "id" : "5d08e0037fa78504fa2cbc59",
  "profileId" : "Save File",
  "description" : "Save File",
  "steps" : [ {
    "taskType" : "readFromEmail",
    "taskDescription" : null,
    "sequenceId" : 1
  }, {
    "taskType" : "storeInSmartStore",
    "taskDescription" : null,
    "sequenceId" : 2
  }, {
    "taskType" : "sendToOCR",
    "taskDescription" : null,
    "sequenceId" : 3
  }, {
    "taskType" : "recognizer",
    "taskDescription" : null,
    "sequenceId" : 4
  }, {
    "taskType" : "storeInLibrary",
    "taskDescription" : null,
    "sequenceId" : 5
  } ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularJS Flow chart  library

[AngularJS Flowchart](https://github.com/ashleydavis/AngularJS-FlowChart)

OR If you want to go with paid service you can use highchart Librarys
[highchart](https://www.highcharts.com/)